# ASP.NET MVC: Cannot fully load a web page. IIS seems to truncate or deny a 'large' image when requesting a page from a slow client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, iis

I have been struggling for a week with an issue I haven't been able to sort out.

I've got a website that is not accessible from outside. It is only visible from the intranet or through VPN connection.

In some of the web pages, I am loading images depending of some variables so that I use Html.RenderAction to load these images.

The website runs fine from a VPN I've got set up (a bit slow because of the server).

But last week I tried to run the web app from a remote client site and a few of its pages didn't load in any browser (IE8, Chrome or Firefox). It only loads part of the page, but then it gets stuck loading the 'large' image.

I have checked with Fiddler and Firebug.

**Fiddler** shows that the browser is loading the page fine, but when it tries to load an image of 145kb through Html.RenderAction, the Body column has value -1 (null?) and it also shows how the browser attempts to reload the same pages several times.

**Firebug** also shows an error within that page, I'm getting a message that says 'Image corrupt or truncated: websiteaddress/GetImage?Id=123'

It looks like when people is not using Internet there (lunch time, for example), the page loads without problem.
I cannot understand as well, how comes the browser attempts to reload the page instead of leaving the jpeg half loaded and keeping on loading the rest of components such as checkboxes and so.

I've tried to remove this Html.RenderAction and the web page loads fine, until it attempts to load another page where there is a ssrs report in pdf (I assume the file is bigger than 145kb as well).

Any help?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sounds like the image request is timing out. Perhaps you could try making the images smaller?

Comment: Thanks, reducing the size of the image fixes the problem, but I cannot do the same with pdfs such as the ones generated by my reporting tool.

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing the [request/response timeout](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/31a2f39c-4d59-4cba-905c-60e7af657e49.mspx?mfr=true) settings in IIS, although it may be that the machine serving these images is not up to the task and is falling over - in which case your best bet is to either reduce the size/number of images it serves, or upgrade the machine (or distribute some resources somewhere else)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll give it a go. I was also thinking about distributing the resources to a faster server.